# Why $\prod_{i=1}^{k-1} \left( 1 - \frac{i}{N}\right) = 1 - \frac{ k \choose 2 }{N}$

Tags: products

In [this biology textbook](https://www.amazon.ca/Population-Genetics-John-H-Gillespie/dp/0801880092/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1468969797&sr=8-1&keywords=guide%20population%20genetics), they show the following equation:

$$\prod_{i=1}^{k-1} \left( 1 - \frac{i}{N}  \right) = 1 - \frac{ k \choose 2 }{N}$$

where both $N$ and $k$ are positive integers and $k < N$.

I fail to prove this equation correct. Can you help me?

Comment: Because it is not correct?  Not even in the limit $k\ll N$.  Are you sure you copied correctly?  I can see that the RHS should be $1-\binom{k}{2}/N$.

Comment: Oh indeed I made a mistake when rewriting the formula in my notes. All right. I still don't know how to prove this correct but I'll give another try. I edited my post in the meantime. Thanks!

Comment: Your equation is still not true. For instance, if $N=5, k=4$ the LHS is $(1-\frac25)\cdot (1-\frac35)=\frac35 \cdot \frac25=\frac6{25}$ and the RHS is $1-\frac65=-0.2$

Comment: Please check your notes again and make an edit.

Comment: It would help if you were more specific about where in the textbook this identity(?) appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is true is that, for fixed $k$ as $N \to \infty$,
$$ \prod_{i=1}^{k-1} \left(1 - \frac{i}{N}\right) = 1 - \frac{{k \choose 2}}{N} + O(1/N^2) $$

EDIT: Taking a few more terms,

$$ \eqalign{\prod_{i=1}^{k-1} \left(1 - \frac{i}{N}\right) &= 1 - \frac{{k \choose 2}}{N} + \dfrac{k(k-1)(k-2)(3k-1)}{24 N^2} - \frac{k^2 (k-1)^2 (k-2)(k-3)}{48 N^3}\cr & + \dfrac{k(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)(k-4)(15k^3-30k^2+5k+2)}{5760 N^4} + O(1/N^5)} $$

Answer (score 3):

Bringing the generic factor to the common denominator, we have:
$$
1 - {i \over N} = {N-i \over N}
$$
So, I am getting this:
$$
\Pi_{i=2}^{k-1} {N-i \over N} = 
{N-2 \over N} \; 
{N-3 \over N} \; 
{N-4 \over N} \; \ldots \;
{N-k+1 \over N}
=
{ {(N-2)! \over (N-k)!} \over N^{k-2}}
$$

Comment: The numerator should be $(N-2)!/(N-k)!$